# Select Bigint colunn return a float number

Tags: sql

id => colunn bigint (7185470932130075125)

```
SELECT id FROM table;
```

But return sql : 7185470932130075000

Why return a around id ?

Comment: I can't confirm that. The id is returned correctly: https://dbfiddle.uk/NVk_SqGM Maybe you consider to provide sufficient information to replicate your issue?

Comment: With sql request, no problem when with node, return float see https://i.ibb.co/0FNgcdp/1.jpg